# Intuition behind the arc length of a curve on the surface and the area of a surface expressed by using first fundamental form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I want to understand the following formulas for defining the arc length of a curve on the surface and the area of a surface from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form):

> (1)$ds^2 = Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2,$
>
> (2)$dA = |X_u \times X_v| \ du\, dv= \sqrt{ \langle X_u,X_u \rangle \langle X_v,X_v \rangle - \langle X_u,X_v \rangle^2 } \ du\, dv = \sqrt{EG-F^2} \, du\, dv.$

I do understand the following formulas for the arc length and area(proved by chopping the arc or surface into small line segments or flakes):

> (3)$L = \int_a^b \sqrt{ (x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2 + (z'(t))^2 } dt$
>
> (4)$A=\iint_D \sqrt{ 1 + (f'(x))^2+(f'(y)) } dxdy$

---

Updated at 11:24pm:

Somehow I can understand (1) from (3) now.
But the understanding of (4) doesn't help me understand (2). What I want is a physicists' "proof" of (2), which may not be rigorous, but well explains the intuition behind the formula (2).

Any solution or reference will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand what $|X_u\times X_v|$ means?

Comment: @JackyChong   The magnitude of a normal vector on the surface?

Comment: Yes. Remember what $|v\times w|$ means in cal 3? It's the area of the parallelogram generated by the two vectors $v$ and $w$.

Comment: @JackyChong the area of a parallelogram with a pair of adjacent sides $v$ and $w$?

Comment: Correct. In short, you are locally approximating the area of the surface by parallelograms generated by the magnitude of the cross product of tangent vectors to the surface.

Comment: @JackyChong Thank you! But this is still not convincing enough for me. I find it hard to express myself at this point. But I think we need to explain why the areas of these parallelograms really denote the areas of flakes on that surface when we chop that surface up(I know this sentence may not convey my ideas clearly).

Comment: In this special case $A=\iint_D \sqrt{ 1 + (f'(x))^2+(f'(y)) } dxdy$, it is easy to explain, because $\sqrt{ 1 + (f'(x))^2+(f'(y)) }$ is the $sec \theta$, where $\theta$ denotes the angle between the normal vector and $z$ axis. However, in $dA = |X_u \times X_v| \ du\, dv$, we don't know why RHS precisely expresses the local area. What if locally we have $dA = 1.732453|X_u \times X_v| \ du\, dv$, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$On a surface, a coordinate system $(u, v)$ gives rise to coordinate vector fields $\dd_{u}$ and $\dd_{v}$ and coordinate differentials $du$ and $dv$. The metric $g$ has components
\begin{align*}
g_{11} = E &= g(\dd_{u}, \dd_{u}) = \|\dd_{u}\|^{2}, \\
g_{22} = G &= g(\dd_{v}, \dd_{v}) = \|\dd_{v}\|^{2}, \\
g_{12} = F &= g(\dd_{u}, \dd_{v}) = \|\dd_{u}\|\, \|\dd_{v}\| \cos\theta,
\end{align*}
with $\theta$ denoting the intrinsic angle between the $u$- and $v$-coordinate curves.

The area of an infinitesimal parallelogram with sides $\dd_{u}$ and $\dd_{v}$ is
$$
\|\dd_{u}\|\, \|\dd_{v}\| \sin\theta
  = \sqrt{\|\dd_{u}\|^{2}\, \|\dd_{v}\|^{2} (1 - \cos^{2}\theta)}
  = \sqrt{EG - F^{2}},
\tag{1}
$$
so that the $2$-form
$$
dA = \sqrt{EG - F^{2}}\, du\, dv
$$
measures the area of an arbitrary infinitesimal parallelogram spanned by an ordered pair of tangent vectors.

If the surface is immersed in Euclidean $3$-space by a mapping $X$ defined in some plane region, then $\dd_{u} = X_{u}$ and $\dd_{v} = X_{v}$ may be viewed as vectors in $\Reals^{3}$. The area of the parallelogram they span is the magnitude of their cross product:
$$
\|X_{u} \times X_{v}\| = \|X_{u}\|\, \|X_{v}\| \sin\theta,
$$
compare (1).

[image: The area element of a surface]